# Adjusting Code using python functions

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

```
#Passwordgen
#Generate a password

def main():

    #Ask the user to input a long string of words, separated by spaces
    sent = input("Enter a sentance separated by spaces: ")

    #Ask the user to input a position within each word
    #Take the position of that word
    pos = eval(input("Input a position within each word: "))
    words = sent.split(" ")

    wordy = ""                                   
    #loops through the word to take the position of the letter
    for word in words:
        wordy = wordy + word[pos] 

    #Prints out the letters as a password
    print("Your password is: ", wordy)  


main()
```

My professor wants me to print out a password generated from that phrase for each position starting from zero up to and including the position the user entered.  It should use the password(phrase, position) function to generate the passwords.

Use string formatting to print each of the password output lines as shown below.

For example:

```
Enter words, separated by spaces: correct horse battery staple
Up to position within each word: 3

Password 0: chbs
Password 1: ooat
Password 2: rrta
Password 3: rstp
```

Comment: What's your question? I only see a project description. Also, why are you using `eval`?

Comment: That's way too broad. What have you tried already? What specifically do you need help with? Answering this question in its current state would just be doing your homework for you. If you have a specific question regarding what you've already tried, we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job on the code so far, just needs a few adjustments:

```
#Passwordgen
#Generate a password

def main():

    #Ask the user to input a long string of words, separated by spaces
    sent = input("Enter a sentance separated by spaces: ")

    #Ask the user to input a position within each word
    #Take the position of that word
    pos = int(input("Input a position within each word: "))
    words = sent.split(" ")

    # set a counter variable to count each password generateed
    count = 0

    #loops through the word to take the position of the letter
    for p in range(pos+1):
        # reset wordy for each new password we are generating
        wordy = ""
        for word in words:
            wordy = wordy + word[p]
        #Prints out the letters as a password
        print("Your password {c} is: {pw}".format(c = count, pw = password))
        count += 1

main()
```

We need to keep track of which position we are taking the letter from in each word, that's what `for p in range(pos+1)` line does (we do `pos+1` to get positions up to `3+1` (or `4`) because range goes up to but not including the value.

Also, as the instructions noted, we need to `"Use string formatting to print each of the password output lines"`, so referring to these [python3 format examples](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples) we can format the output of each password, with the associated count.

Hope this helps you, cheers!

Comment: Should I always abbreviate my variable to make it easier to string format or was there a particular reason you did it this way?

print("Your password {c} is: {pw}".format(c = count, pw = password))
        count += 1

Comment: No there is no reason I abbreviated the variables, you can name them anything that seems reasonable for you :) I think I just named them abbreviations because I didn't want to fill the code with long variable names that make it hard to read. sorry if it is confusing. Definitely use better variable names if you can. The format method can take variables to associate the sequential parameters, but you can name the variables anything that make better sense for you.